# Equivalent urllib.parse.quote() in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

What is the equivalent of `urllib.parse.quote`

It's `urllib.urlencode()`?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you are looking for [urllib.pathname2url](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.pathname2url). Compare:

Python 3, [urllib.parse.quote](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote):

```
>>> urllib.parse.quote('abc def/foo?bar=baz')
'abc%20def/foo%3Fbar%3Dbaz'
```

Python 2, [urllib.pathname2url](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.pathname2url):

```
>>> urllib.pathname2url('abc def/foo?bar=baz')
'abc%20def/foo%3Fbar%3Dbaz'
```

The behavior seems similar to me, but they might be subtly different.

**Edit:**

Reading your comment on Algina's post, I think this is my preferred way to build the url:

```
>>> url = 'http://dev.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search'
>>> params = {'api_key': 'xxxx', 'format': 'json', 'artist': 'Galaxie 500'}
>>> "{}?{}".format(url, urllib.urlencode(params))
'http://dev.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search?api_key=xxxx&artist=Galaxie+500&format=json'
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

Answer (score 17):

actually using the library `six`, which is made for python2/python3 compatibility you can do

```
import six.moves.urllib as urllib 

# and now you can use urllib as it was python3
urllib.quote(...)
```

and if you just want python2, it was actually `urllib.quote` directly

Comment: Hi @allan.simon, I have the `six (1.10.0)` package installed and I'm getting `AttributeError: 'Module_six_moves_urllib' object has no attribute 'quote'`.. Any idea why?

Comment: Seems I needed `urllib.parse.quote(...)` (actually in my case I needed `urllib.parse.quote_plus(...)`).

Comment: this is because the `six.moves.urllib` namespace implements Python3's `urllib` namespace. This is to encourage one to write code in a Py3-compatible way while still in a Py2 environment.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific?
you have 
`urllib.parse.quote_plus(...)
urllib.parse.quote_from_bytes(...)
urllib.parse.unquote(...)` 
like you mentioned

see doc here:
https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/urllib.parse.html

Comment: Thanks,
I have `req = 'http://dev.echonest.com/api/v4/song/search?api_key=xxxx&format=json&artist=' + urllib.parse.quote(artist)`
And `artist = "Oasis"`